# changing spritekitnode image

Tags: xcode, image, ipad, sprite-kit

I'm doing a number of tutorials for the new sprite kit for Xcode, but for the next part, I need to change the images of a number of nodes. For example, I have three images which need to change every time a button is clicked. The only way I've found to do this is to addChild every time it updates, but that makes the program run WAY TOO SLOW.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) SKSpriteNode * button;
@property (nonatomic, strong) JSTileMap *map;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Player *player;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSTimeInterval previousUpdateTime;
@property (nonatomic, strong) TMXLayer *walls;
@property (nonatomic, strong) TMXLayer *hazards;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL gameOver;
@property (nonatomic, strong) SKSpriteNode *selectedNode;
@property (nonatomic, strong)SKTexture *butt1;
@property (nonatomic, strong)SKTexture *butt2;
@property (nonatomic, strong)SKTexture *butt3;
@end

@implementation GameLevelScene

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
   if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
_button = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"b1.png"];
[_button setName:kAnimalNodeName];
[_button setPosition:CGPointMake(500,200)];
_button.zPosition =15;
_butt1= [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"b1.png"];
_butt2= [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"b2.png"];
_butt3= [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"b3.png"];
[self addChild:_button];

[[SKTAudio sharedInstance] playBackgroundMusic:@"level1.mp3"];
[[SKTAudio sharedInstance] playSoundEffect:@"intro2.mp3"];
self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:.4 green:.4 blue:.95 alpha:1.0];
self.map = [JSTileMap mapNamed:@"cl1.tmx"];
[self addChild:self.map];
self.walls = [self.map layerNamed:@"walls"];
self.hazards = [self.map layerNamed:@"hazards"];
self.player = [[Player alloc] initWithImageNamed:@"cuberta1"];
self.player.position = CGPointMake(100, 250);
self.player.zPosition = 15;
[self.map addChild:self.player];
self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
   }
 return self;
 }

 - (void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime{
  if (self.gameOver) return;
   if(mode == 1){
NSLog(@"AAAAAAAAA");
_button = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"b1.png"];
_button = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:_butt1];
[_button setName:kAnimalNodeName];
[_button setPosition:CGPointMake(500,200)];
_button.zPosition =15;
[self addChild:_button];
    }else if (mode == 2){
NSLog(@"BBBBBBBBBB");
_button = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"b2.png"];
_button = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:_butt2];
[_button setName:kAnimalNodeName];
[_button setPosition:CGPointMake(500,200)];
_button.zPosition =15;
[self addChild:_button];
   }else if (mode == 3){
NSLog(@"CCCCCCCCC");
_button = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"b3.png"];
_button = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:_butt3];
[_button setName:kAnimalNodeName];
[_button setPosition:CGPointMake(500,200)];
_button.zPosition =15;
[self addChild:_button];
   }



 - (void)selectNodeForTouch:(CGPoint)touchLocation {
     //1  WHICH NODE IS SELECTED
     SKSpriteNode *touchedNode = (SKSpriteNode *)[self nodeAtPoint:touchLocation];
    if([[touchedNode name] isEqualToString:kAnimalNodeName]) {


  if (mode == 3) {
    NSLog(@"DERP");
    mode = 1;
  }else if(mode == 2){
    NSLog(@"QWE");
    mode = 3;
  }else if (mode == 1) {
    NSLog(@"ASF");
    mode = 2;
  }


}

 }
```

Comment: button.texture = newTexture. Also change button.size = newTexture.size if the size of the textures is different.

Comment: - (void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime{
  if (self.gameOver) return;
  if(mode == 1){
    NSLog(@"AAAAAAAAA");
 still didn't work
    _button.texture = _butt1;
    _button.size= _butt1.size;
  }else if (mode == 2){
    NSLog(@"BBBBBBBBBB");

    _button.texture = _butt2;
    _button.size= _butt2.size;
  }else if (mode == 3){
    NSLog(@"CCCCCCCCC");
    _button.texture = _butt3;
    _button.size= _butt3.size;
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than re-adding a bunch of images every tap, make all of your images up front, position them properly, then use the SKNode property "hidden" to show or hide them.

Assuming your images don't dynamically change to different textures, that should be a lot faster than re-creating the sprites all the time.